# Sketch in $x-y$ plane based on set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem:** 
Would the sketch of the following set of points in the x-y plane be infinitely many diagonal lines ($y=x$) each passing through points at integer intervals on the y-axis, e.g. $(0, y):y\in\mathbb Z$?
$$
\{(x, x+y):x\in\mathbb R,y\in\mathbb Z\}
$$

**What I know:** 
The y-coordinate value is described as $x + y$ with $y\in\mathbb Z$. 
So, for $x=0$, the point is $(0,y)$. In other words, at $x$ equal to $0$, the sketch would include points at each integer on the y-axis.  
Similarly, for $x=1$, the point is $(1,1 + y)$.  
And for $x=0.000001$, the point is $(0.000001,0.000001 +y)$. 
Fixing $y=1$, the point is $(x,x + 1)$. In other words, the line is diagonal like $y=x + 1$.

**What I don't know:** 
Well, I don't know what I don't know and just asking for confirmation here.

[citation](https://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Erhammack/BookOfProof/): "Book of Proof" by Richard Hammock, Chapter 1 Exercise question 49

Comment: Yes. You are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{(x, x+y):x\in\mathbb R,y\in\mathbb Z\}$ is the set of lines of the form $y=x+n,$ where $n\in\mathbb Z:$ $$\{(x, x+y):x\in\mathbb R,y\in\mathbb Z\}
\\=\{y=x+n:x\in\mathbb R,n\in\mathbb Z\}
\\=\ldots\{y=x-2:x\in\mathbb R\}\cup\{y=x-1:x\in\mathbb R\}\cup
\{y=x:x\in\mathbb R\}\cup\{y=x+1:x\in\mathbb R\}\cup\{y=x+2:x\in\mathbb R\}\cup\ldots.$$

P.S. On a side note, because the variables in the given set $\{(x, x+y):x\in\mathbb R,y\in\mathbb Z\}$ are bound, it can also be written as, say, $\{(u, u+v):u\in\mathbb R,v\in\mathbb Z\}.$

Comment: The $y=x+n$ really clarified this for me. It was confusing to see $y$ being used for the x-y plane and as a variable name for the y-coordinate value and maybe that was the point of the question.

Comment: @2q. I'm sure the misleading notation choice was not the point of the question. But it is misleading.

Comment: @2q. The author's notation choice is indeed misleading. I've added a postscript in response to your comment.